# How to put jar file in embed tag in html

Tags: java, html, applet

i have applet tag that have the following

```
<applet id="ZFComponent"
      codebase="java.code.webcomponents.ZFApplet" archive="ZFApplet.jar" width="0" height="0">
This browser does not support Embed.
  </applet>
```

and i want to use embed tag instated to make it work in Mozilla family of browsers

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the class that you want do embed from the jar file.

Like this:

```
<applet id="ZFComponent" ARCHIVE="ZFApplet.jar" CODE="ZFApplet.class" width="0" height="0">
This browser does not support Embed.
 </applet>
```

This is assuming the class you want to embed is `ZFApplet`.

---

**EDIT:** The above code will work on some browsers but it is going extinct because using `applet` tags introduces a lot of security risks.  Chrome no longer supports the `applet` tag and you should only be running Java in Chrome through [*Java Web Start*](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) (and even with that it prompts the user about running Java.)

See [the notice on Oracle's site](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml):

> Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)
>   The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin architecture NPAPI, which has been supported by all major web browsers for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 (scheduled for release in September 2015) drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based plugins.
>
> Java applications are offered through web browsers as either a web
>   start application (which do not interact with the browser once they
>   are launched) or as a Java applet (which might interact with the
>   browser). This change does not affect Web Start applications, it only
>   impacts applets.
>
> If you have problems accessing Java applications using Chrome, Oracle
>   recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X)
>   instead.

***Happy Coding!***

Comment: this tag is working is fine in IE but i need to make it work in chrome so i need to use <embed> tag

Comment: I'm sorry.  I didn't realize this was about a browser compatibility issue.  You can't use `<embed>` for jar files, and seem my edit to my answer.